# Disable Gallery until popup is displayed

Tags: android, scroll, gallery

I m using a full screen gallery in my project and with gallery i am using supporting base adapter of gallery 
    now i have to make gallery disable/stop scrolling of gallery until popup is displayed in on button click 
    can any one help me out in this matter ?

-->    below is the  snippet i m using base adapter for gallery and not extending gallery.

```
public class SubItemSelectedImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    private Context mContext;
    private String[] mImageIds;
    ImageView[] mImages;

    public SubItemSelectedImageAdapter(Context c, String[] mImageIds2) {

        mImageIds = mImageIds2;
        mImages = new ImageView[mImageIds.length];
        mContext = c;
        TypedArray attr = mContext
                .obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.HelloGallery);
        attr.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mImageIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {


        return position;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

        imageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File(mImageIds[position])));
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

        return imageView;
    }
}

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

and delaring Gallery object and refrence it from xml ...

```
    // full screen gallery implementation.
    ImageAdapter = new SubItemSelectedImageAdapter(this, data);
    Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);

    gallery.setAdapter(ImageAdapter);
```

Comment: hey use setOnTouchListener(this) and implement the method and whenever a touch appear on view handle it in the ontouch by return flase ..might solve your problem or another way you can go for is that extends gallery and override onFling method and use android:onscroll="false" shall solve your problem and let me know

Comment: i can't extend gallery so if i go for ur 1st answer to implement setontouchlistner(this) how can i set gallery scroll disable when popup is displayed

Comment: hey why can't you extends gallery or instead use onfling  method and make your code wait until you have displayed the popup ... like have a static boolean popupStatus = false; "\n" while (!popupstatus){} for that you have to extends gallery I think ....

Comment: i got the way as u told to implement ontouchlistner thank u so much for this idea i m editing the answer

Comment: use setOnTouchListener() of gallery as below and use flag for the enable disable process
 -  on popup being display make flag false and when there is no popup  being displayed make flag false.
 - code is as below:


gallery.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
   
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(flag==true){
     return false;
    }else{
     
     return true;
    }
    
   }
  });


thanks to vipin sahu

Comment: that what I am trying to say.. so finally you are done with .. but why are you not extending gallery ... if you could ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use setOnTouchListener() of gallery as below and use flag for the enable disable process 
- on popup being display make flag false and when there is no popup being displayed make flag false. 
- code is as below: 
gallery.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
{ public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
 { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 if(flag==true){ return false;
 }else{
 return true; 
}
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your on Button Click Event you can disable Gallery by Below code.

```
gallery.setEnabled(false);
```

this will make it non clickable and also it can not be scrollable .
when you done with your popup make is enable.

```
 gallery.setEnabled(true);
```